# Only getting the first character when accessing post variable

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, form-submit

A common way I handle things in Drupal is to create a CCK type, and then create a custom submit handler to perform logic on the CCK fields when the node is submitted. However, I have been unable to get the value when the CCK field type is a Date field because the array is structured differently.

UPDATE - João Guilherme had a much simpler approach, but I still couldn't get the date value out of the array posted below.

```
$fromDate = $form['field_bill_start'][0]['#value'];
drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($fromDate, TRUE) .'</pre>');

//Which then prints this.
Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [date] => Tue, 08/24/2010
        )

)
```

I then tried adding these which printed null. I also tried the "#" before date and value.

```
['value']['date']
```

*************************Original Post**********************************

```
<?php
 function billing_form_billing_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  //drupal_set_message('We are hooking it!');
  $form['#submit'][] = 'billing_submit_function';
}

function billing_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  $fromDatePRE = array();
  $fromDatePRE[] =  $form['field_bill_start'][0]['value']['date'];
  $fromDate[] = $fromDatePRE[0]['#value']['#date'];

  drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($fromDatePRE[0], TRUE) .'</pre>');


  drupal_set_message("From Date = ".$fromDate[0]);
  drupal_set_message("From Date2 = ".$fromDatePRE[0]);
```

**$fromDate is printing the first character "S" of Sat 8/21/2010 which is the value I want** , but I want the whole value. I know this has something do with how I'm accessing the array but I can't figure it out.

This is what I'm working with - I added a comment to the value I'm trying to access:

Which Yiedls:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [#type] => textfield
                [#default_value] => Sat, 08/21/2010
                [#id] => edit-field-bill-start-0-value-datepicker-popup-0
                [#size] => 20
                [#maxlength] => 30
                [#attributes] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [#description] =>  Format: Sat, 08/21/2010
                [#post] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => llllllllllllll
                        [menu] => Array
                            (
                                [link_title] => 
                                [parent] => Array
                                    (
                                        [hierarchical_select] => Array
                                            (
                                                [selects] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => primary-links:0
                                                        [1] => label_1
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [weight] => 0
                            )

                        [hs_form_build_id] => hs_form_7bf97c3c59ba2a064d6e841ae405dd30
                        [changed] => 
                        [form_build_id] => form-1f928faaa990f3809da391165d51981a
                        [form_token] => 616f6e8a7bb9c4ffc2aec65174c0817d
                        [form_id] => billing_node_form
                        [log] => 
                        [pathauto_perform_alias] => 1
                        [print_display] => 1
                        [print_display_urllist] => 1
                        [print_mail_display] => 1
                        [print_mail_display_urllist] => 1
                        [print_pdf_display] => 1
                        [print_pdf_display_urllist] => 1
                        [field_bill_start] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => Array
                                            (
                                                //This is the value I need
                                                [date] => Sat, 08/21/2010
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [field_bill_end] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => Array
                                            (
                                                [date] => 08/25/2010
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [name] => administrator
                        [date] => 
                        [status] => 1
                        [promote] => 1
                        [op] => Save
                    )

                [#programmed] => 
                [#tree] => 1
                [#parents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => field_bill_start
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => value
                        [3] => date
                    )

                [#array_parents] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => field_bill_start
                        [1] => 0
                        [2] => value
                        [3] => date
                    )

                [#weight] => 0
                [#processed] => 1
                [#required] => 
                [#input] => 1
                [#autocomplete_path] => 
                [#process] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => form_expand_ahah
                    )

                [#name] => field_bill_start[0][value][date]
                [#value] => Sat, 08/21/2010
                [#needs_validation] => 1
                [#defaults_loaded] => 1
                [#sorted] => 1
            )

    )
```

Comment: You wrote `$fromDate = ['0']['#value']['#date']`, which would not give you back any value. What is the variable containing the array you are trying to access?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - You were correct. I have updated the code. Now what is showing is producing "S"

Comment: @cinqoTimo - what is the object that you dumb its value to get the result in your original post ?

Comment: @iKid - I don't understand your question. I am getting these results from the $form array. I'm not sure if it's an "object" in Drupal as PHP typically uses $object->property for OOP notation, and this is an array.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question. I'm no drupal expert but is the drupal_set_message doing something funny with the value when you add ['value']['date']? Have you tried just print_r or var_dump without the  drupal_set_message call?

Comment: @cinqoTimo yes, you're right, i'm not careful with my word, am asking which variable exactly. If it's $form then your date should be in 
$form[0]['#post']['field_bill_start'][0]['value']['date'] unless you're printing the wrong variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the value submitted by the user which is on the `$form_state`;

I tested with a single date field, instead of a datefield with 2 values. But this should work just fine anyways. I might have the naming of your field incorrect, but you can check out the values on `$form_state['values']`, where you should find your field listed.

Anyways the code would look something like this:

```
function billing_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
  $from_date =  $form_state['values']['field_bill_start'][0]['value'];
  $from_date_string = format_date(strtotime($from_date), 'custom', 'D d/m/Y');
  $from_date_2 =  $form_state['values']['field_bill_start'][0]['value2'];
  $from_date_string_2 = format_date(strtotime($from_date_2), 'custom', 'D d/m/Y');

  drupal_set_message("From Date = ".$from_date_string);
  drupal_set_message("From Date2 = ".$from_date_string_2);
}
```

Comment: @googletop - You are correct - what you posted pulls the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

The return you get is because you are accessing a string, and not an array.

```
$string = "ABCDEFG";
// This would print "A".
print $string[0];
```

To notice then that a submission handler takes the submitted values from `$form_state['values']`, not from `$form`.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying lots of different things to try to get this to work. I posted the wrong snippet..

Comment: Not sure I follow you. If I'm in the wrong array - why can I get the first letter of the value I need? Can you show me what you mean by $form_state['values']

Comment: See [`user_edit_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_edit_submit/6), [`book_outline_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/book_outline_form_submit/6), and [`comment_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/comment_form_submit/6); none of those submission handlers get the submitted values from `$form`. As per the error you are describing, the problem is using a string thinking it is an array; in both the cases, `$variable[0]` is a valid expression, but for a string it would return the first character (which is not what you want, in this case).

Comment: What is posted is accessing the correct value - I can see it in the array, and I am able to get the first character. As for accessing a string like it is an array, I understand that, but when I leave off the index it prints nothing, so it is not as simple as your example suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, I deleted my previous answer once I really looked at the code and noticed I was way off before. There seems to be a lot of redundant arrays created that in my opinion are just confusing the issue. Does this work?

```
$fromDate = $form[0]['#post']['field_bill_start'][0]['value']['date'];
drupal_set_message("From Date = ".$fromDate);
```

EDIT:

Updated the code to have another try

Comment: Thanks, I agree about the needless arrays. What you provided prints - From Date = ""(nothing)  and  From Date2 = Array

Comment: I've updated the code, would you mind trying again?

If the output you have in your question is coming from the print_r($fromDatePRE) statement then this new code should work I think

Comment: Thanks for having a second look. I know that looks right but it's null. I'm thinking of just using a textbox (which I can easily capture the value!?) and use a Jquery calendar to set the value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to print `$form['field_bill_start'][0]['#value']`.

**Update:** print directly the `$form['field_bill_start'][0]['#value']`, don't add it to a variable or array.

Comment: I updated my post with the results of a print_r. I thought I could add the array levels like shown.